# Make form elements wait until async / await finishes

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, multithreading, design-patterns

I have a simple application that is using async / await (.NET 4.0 with async targeting package) to communicate with a db and return result.

I need to alter the behavior of some form elements until the data are available. For simple implementations i would like to disable form elements until the data are available. Or change the behavior of the click events on form elements.

What is the proper way of doing it?

I have thought of

- Having some boolean property to let the elements know that the thread is operating.
- Use eventing form the button that does the work? (I suspect this is the solution but please elaborate on how)

Thanks.

Comment: What behavior must be changed, and how?

Comment: @RoyDictus: Upadted the question

Comment: @L.B: I want my form to be operable for some elements.

Comment: Do you want them to *start off* disabled, or is this in response to some user input? What API does your data source expose?

Comment: @JonSkeet: I press on a button that makes a data access call and i am using async / await (as you pointed out in another thread). While this is happening i need to disable 10-20 form elements. I hate to believe that i nee dto do it with a boolean property ...I thought that observer pattern (or something similar) would be appropriate..

Comment: The entire point of `async` / `await` is that you **don't** "wait". Just disable those portions of the UI if you need to, and handle it in the callback.

Comment: @MarcGravell: I dont want to wait .I am just asking what is the proper way of disabling the ui elements i don't want. And also what i do if i dont just want to disable elements but alter their events behavior when a task is running.

Comment: @e4rthdog: You can still change properties within a disabled control - it just won't accept user input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be as simple as the code we saw in your other question. Logically you want:

```
foo.Enabled = false;
bar.Enabled = false;
// etc
await Task.Run(...);
foo.Enabled = true;
bar.Enabled = true;
```

Now you can make that a lot simpler if you put all the controls that need this treatment together:

```
SetEnabled(controlCollection, false);
await Task.Run(...);
SetEnabled(controlCollection, true);

...

private static void SetEnabled(IEnumerable<Control> controls, bool enabled)
{
    foreach (var control in controls)
    {
        control.Enabled = enabled;
    }
}
```

Comment: For the simple disabling this is the way to go. I just didn't know if the best practice even for such simple things is to go with Observer pattern , as Anders is proposing...

Comment: Well, the reason to go with the Design Pattern solutions is usually that their properties are know. In this case: Observer scales well for the task at hand. The only place you need to add anythin if youa dd a new type of form element is in the code local to it, not in the code for dispatching the database lookup. But sure, if you only have two fields just go ahead and implement :) But you DID tag your question "Design patterns" :D

Answer (score 1):

The way to go is with some kind of observer pattern. It's the most generic solution.

So:

```
public interface ObserveDataAvailable {
  public void dataIsAvailable(final Data data);
}

public class ObserveDataAvailableComposite {
  private final List<ObserveDataAvailable> items = new LinkedList<ObserveDataAvailable>();

  public add(final ObserveDataAvailable item) {
    items.add(item);
  }

  public add(final List<ObserveDataAvailable> items) {
    this.items.addAll(items);
  }


  public void dataIsAvailable(final Data data) {
    for (final ObserveDataAvailable item : items) {
      item.dataIsAvailable(item);
    }
  }
}

public class ActivateFormelementWhenDataAvailable {
  private final FormElement fe;

  public ActivateFormelementWhenDataAvailable(final FormElement fe) {
    this.fe = fe;
  }

  public void dataIsAvailable(final Data data) {
    fe.set(data);
    fe.activate();
  }
}


// Run in thread
private void doDataLookup(final ObserveDataAvailable onCompletion) {
  final Data data = getDataFromDb();
  onCOmpletion.dataIsAvailable(data);
}
```

Now you can do:

```
final ObserveDataAvailable onCompletion = new ObserveDataAvailable();
<add the form elements>
runInThread(doDataLookup(onCompletion);
```